# Wordpress alongside Codeignitier?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, codeigniter

I have ci installed in root and wordpress inside wordpress directory.
I already allowed wordpress to use root by setting site url and main .htaccess to rewrite wordpress directory, but because ci is inside root i have url conflict between ci and wordpress..
You know that ci using pretty links, so when i try to run this for example:

> example.com/ci_class/ci_function

It's redirects me to wordpress template with message

> Not Found

This happens probably because i included wordpress wp-load.php inside index.php of codeignitier...

What i can to do?
I want to use wordpress functions inside ci, but i also want that ci url works fine...

Comment: You have to distinct URLs somehow. Application can't know if visitor need CI or WP if typed `example.com/something` i.e. if it is CI route or WP post. Suggestion would be to leave WP directory in URL and call it appropriate like blog or something suitable.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I already use it like you describe, but than i had problems like is cookie. Because WP using cookie inside directory where he is, but i want to use that wp cookie inside ci.

Comment: Check if [this search](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/105736/how-to-get-login-data-session-outside-wordpress#answer-105836) is helping.

Comment: I already tried root cookie and some other suggestions but it is not good solution because i have some other problems. Is possible to set prority inside .htaccess? I want that ci has priority if is not found trybin wordpress else 404?